# Using Javascript to remove end of URL

Tags: javascript

Using window.location.pathname I get "/Mobile/Evol/12-20-2011".

Using Javascript, how could I drop off everything after "Evol/" so that I get "/Mobile/Evol/"?

Comment: BTW, what's your real goal?

Comment: @MaratTanalin I second that. From what you wrote, it isn't clear what, in general, you're **actually** trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a combination of the `substring()` and `lastIndexOf()` functions to easily cut off everything after the last `/`:

```
uri    = "/Mobile/Evol/12-20-2011";
newUri = uri.substring(0, uri.lastIndexOf('/'));
```

as @josh points out if there are more directories after "/Evol", this fails. You can fix this by searching for the string 'Evol/' then adding its length back to the substring end:

```
dir = "Evol/";
newUri = uri.substring(0, uri.lastIndexOf(dir) + dir.length);
```

Chrome console gives me this output:

```
> uri    = "/Mobile/Evol/12-20-2011";
"/Mobile/Evol/12-20-2011"

> dir = "Evol/";
  newUri = uri.substring(0, uri.lastIndexOf(dir) + dir.length);
"/Mobile/Evol/"
```

Comment: This assumes there's only one directory after `Evol`, which may not be correct.

Comment: @josh3736 that is correct, I was only following the example that was posted. I edited to take account for your comment.

Answer (score 2):

Just use "split" function in JavaScript string,

```
var url = '/Mobile/Evol/12-20-2011';
var tokens = url.split('/');
var reqURL = token[0] + '/'+ token[1] ;
```

Of course the URL format must be the same some_string/some_string/some_string

Answer (score 0):

```
var str = window.location.pathname;
const sub = "Evol/";

var locEvol = str.indexOf(sub);
var endIdx = locEvol + sub.length;
var beginStr = str.substring(0, endIdx);
// beginStr contains the desired substring
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to cut off any query and fragment completely:

```
url.replace(/\/Evol\/[^?#]*(?:[?#].*)?$/, '/Evol')
```

To break this regex down:

1. `\/Evol\/` matches the literal text `"/Evol/"`.  The `\`'s are necessary since `//Evol/...` would be a line comment, and a `/` elsewhere in a regex ends the regex.
2. `[^?#]` matches anything except a query or fragment delimiter
3. `(?:...)?` just makes something optional
4. `[?#].*` matches a query or fragment start followed by any number of non-whitespace chars
5. `$` forces the match to reach the end of the input.

Answer (score 0):

One Liner:

```
match.url.split("/").slice(0,-1).join("/")
```

```js
let array1 = "/first/second/third/fourth";
let array2="posts/stories/1234";

console.log("Result=",array1.split("/").slice(0,-1).join("/"));
console.log("Result=",array2.split("/").slice(0,-1).join("/"));
```